# MultiSelect Videos not playing in xamarin forms android

Tags: image, video, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, multi-select

We are using below link for multiselect photos/videos in xamarin forms both android and ios. https://www.xamboy.com/2019/03/12/select-multiple-images-and-videos-in-xamarin-forms/

After multiselect the video, click play button video need to play. First we are using crossmedia for single select, that time video played properly. Now we are using multiselect refered above mentioned link. After multiselect the videos, video not playing in android. In IOS this was working fine. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question: are you getting any error? Exception? What do you see when you debug?

Comment: Not getting any error. After selected the video, click play button video need to play.  First we are using crossmedia for single select, that time video played properly. Now we are useing multiselect refered above mentioned link. Now video not playing

Comment: I am checking the sample code you provided. Have you do any changes when you selected the videos?